# How to deal with case sensitive files in git?

Tags: git, version-control, case-insensitive

My team works on multiple operating system (Windows, Unix). We have a unix server and our local machines are windows.

We face issues with our github repository as Unix is case sensitive so our repo has files with same names in different case. So cloning the repository removes one of those files.

What is the best way to deal with this issue? Is there a standard convention?

Comment: Standard convention is to treat all of your filenames as if they are case insensitive.

Comment: You can change the [core.ignorecase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.14.6/#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase) or create a [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for it

Comment: I would argue that case-sensitive file systems exist because certain name "look" better if you can use one case or the other, not because having different file names that differ only in case is a good idea. (That's definitely the case with the various file systems developed by Apple, which does not *distinguish* between `foo.txt` and `FOO.txt`, but *preserves* the case used when the file was created.) (1/2)

Comment: Point being, creating file names that differ only by case may be a bad idea, but Git might be able to accommodate them. (`core.ignorecase` is similar to the case-preserving idea; you'll need a custom hook to rename files that will collide in the target system if case sensitivity is unavailable.) (2/2)

Comment: The title is asking the wrong question. Git deals with case-sensitive file names just fine; you need a way to map such file names to unique names on your Windows machines.

Comment: **Do not** alter `core.ignorecase` unless you know *exactly* what you are doing. Git uses the setting to predict what your computer will do; it does not control what your computer actually does. If you mis-set it on purpose to fool Git, and things go wrong and you lose some file(s), this is your fault, not Git's.

Answer (score 3):

In general, the way to make this work across systems is to adopt a convention for the proper casing of file names and stick to it, and if possible, enforce it in CI.  This is the best way to make things work on systems which don't properly handle file names that differ in case.

For example, if you're working with Java files, then the convention is to name those files with the same case as the case of the class which they contain.  If you're working with files in Rust, typically they should always be in lowercase.  If your language doesn't have a convention, or you're not sure what to do, prefer lowercase file names.  These are easier to type on Unix systems, which are case-sensitive, since the user doesn't need to deal with holding down Shift.

Whatever you do, enforce the convention in CI, just like any other codebase convention, so that users don't accidentally check in files that don't meet the standards.  Ideally you'll also have a script that users can run on their systems to help them check before they submit as well.  This scripting can be done with `git ls-files` for the index or `git ls-tree -r` for commits or trees.

For the existing files, you'll need to remove or rename one of the offending files.  You can do this on a Unix system with `git mv` or `git rm`, as appropriate.

Comment: I completely agree.  Considering workarounds like "core.ignorecase" in this scenario is a *BAD IDEA*.  The OP should 1) decide on an appropriate convention, 2) Rename any existing objects in Git accordingly, 3) Adhere to the convention going forward.  Using  [pre-commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and add check_case_conflict are also good ideas.  See also: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/git-is-casesensitive-and-your-filesystem-may-not-be-weird-folder-merging-on-windows

Comment: I agree hooks can be useful, but they should be optional for users because hooks, especially pre-commit hooks, can be very irritating for users who use workflows with many fixup commits that they then squash.  But for users who want to use them, they can be valuable.

Comment: I agree that hooks should be "optional".  Similarly, I'm not saying "core.ignorecase is Bad" - it, too, can be "useful".  But in this particular scenario: 1) the team should NOT rely on "core.ignorecase" (just because it might appear "convenient"), and 2) SHOULD consider every means possible to enforce "correct naming conventions" (including using automated "hooks").  In any case: your response is good.  Including the part about "rename" as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

On Mac/Linux machines, unset `core.ignorecase`:

> git config --unset core.ignorecase

And on Windows, set it to `true`:

> git config --global core.ignorecase true

A better way is to use [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/#intro) and add [check_case_conflict](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/blob/master/pre_commit_hooks/check_case_conflict.py) to its config file

Comment: `ignorecase` won't help if you already have, for example, `foo.txt` and `FOO.txt` in the repository.

Comment: @chepner You're right. If it's already in the repository, @vandit-goel need to use `git mv`, for example: `git mv FOO.txt foo.txt`, then commit again

Comment: Well, not that `git mv`, because you'll just overwrite the original `foo.txt` with `FOO.txt`. But renaming to *something* is necessary.

Comment: `core.ignorecase` is designed to be set by Git based on the file system, and it shouldn't be modified by the user.  It's designed to reflect accurately whether the file system folds case or not.

Comment: for the record : running `mv FOO.txt foo.txt` on a ci file system is a noop, and generally the system will not change the actual name on disk (seen on Windows). This is also true for `git mv` (at least for the "files on disk" part). The easiest workaround is to use a temporary name : `mv FOO.txt tempfile.txt && mv tempfile.txt foo.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you clone a repository, you get its *commits*.  Each Git commit stores a full copy of every file, in a special, read-only, Git-only format, which *is* case-sensitive.  This means you have not actually *lost* any files.

The thing is, to *use* a file *from* some Git commit, you must have Git *extract* that file from the commit.  Each commit's files are stored as a sort of archive, like a tarball or zip-file: your computer can't work with *these* files directly.  So `git checkout` or `git switch` will *extract* the committed files into what Git calls your *working tree*.

Your working tree uses ordinary OS files, and if your OS / file-system is case-insensitive—as the default file systems on Windows and macOS are—it is *that file system* that cannot store both `File.ext` *and* `file.ext`.  Git itself is not really confused by this, but the fact that your *system* will only store *one* of these files means that it's very difficult to *use* Git after this point.  (It's not impossible—you can use low-level commands, that Git calls *plumbing* commands, to work with these files.  But it *is* impractical.)

As in [bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68461802/1256452), usually the "right way" to deal with this is just to establish a convention, and avoid storing these problematic file names in future commits.  Note that case-sensitivity is not the only issue here: Windows will not be able to extract a file named `aux.h`, for instance, and macOS cannot distinguish between two files whose names differ only in [composing forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) (s c h o combining-umlaut n vs s c h o-with-umlaut n: these are different byte sequences, and Git and Linux will store both, but macOS won't).